# In what order does OpenGL ES 2.0 read the elements of a matrix?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm confused.  Is it:

```
0 ,1 , 2, 3
4 ,5 , 6, 7
8 ,9 ,10,11
12,13,14,15
```

or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL matrix order is column major:

```
0, 4, 8,  12
1, 5, 9,  13
2, 6, 10, 14
3, 7, 11, 15
```

There is a set of functions to load, multiply, ... line major matrices: [glLoadTransposeMatrix](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLoadTransposeMatrix.xml).

Comment: Those functions don't work under ES 2.0.  You have to do it all manually.  But thanks for the byte order!